Incomplete type cannot be defined
I am attempting to set up some header files for a game, however, attempting to set up variables in my main file's header file causes an incomplete type error.
Both types have full definitions in their own .cpp files, but the .hpp files have the error.
#include "Map.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Player;

int map;
MapData mapdata;
Player player;

The lines
MapData mapdata;
Player player;

say _____ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
(relevant line of Map.hpp):
class MapData;

This question is similar to: When does an Incomplete Type error occur in C++. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Why didn't you include "Player.hpp"?

class definitions in header file. class implementations in .cpp files. The error messages are correct, as the definitions aren't visible. Putting the class definitons in the header files (not just a forward declaration) and including them should resolve this issue. Note: unlike some other languages, member function implementations do not have to be provided as part of the class definition, they can be provided later.

There has to be a class definition (class Player { void play(); }, or whatever visible at the point where you create the object. Classes are usually defined in header files, with their implementations in .cpp files.

class Player; most of the time you don't want forward declarations in the source file. In the header it makes sense but in the source file you need to be able to create instances.

Your class statements are just forward-declarations. You are stating that the types exist but not what they look like. You can't instantiate an object when its type is just forward declared, you need the full type declaration.

Fixed, the solution was to replace the forward Declarations like class Player with declarations of them and their attributes.

For types, the correct thing is indeed to have them in header files. This includes classes like Player. You do not need to put the method bodies in the header file (and unless they are templated you generally shouldn’t), but the full definition of the class — that is, everything that is needed to be known about its layout and how to call its methods — that should be available before it is used anywhere.
The purpose of a forward declaration for a class is to make a pointer to that class possible before the full definition of that class is provided.
Thus your file should look something like:
#include <iostream>

#include "Map.hpp"
#include "Player.hpp"

int map;
MapData mapdata;
Player player;

You would then have separate files “Map.hpp”, “Map.cpp”, “Player.hpp”, and “Player.cpp”, in addition to the main program file partially listed here.
